# Calling a local within speech quotes

Tags: r, save, local-variables

I have defined my start and end dates for reading in data as objects, and after running a simple calculation, I want to be able to save the estimated object using the end date within the speech quotes.
For example:

```
start_date <- "28-02-2020"
end_date <- "28-04-2020"
result <- 2 + 3
saveRDS(result, paste0(results_folder, "ouput_"end_date".RDS")
```

What I want is for R to be able to read the 'end_date' as the assigned date and save the result file as "output_28-04-2020.RDS"

I use both start and end dates multiple times in the code and it would be easier if the option to save the results as mentioned would be available

Comment: Could you define `x`, `y`, `results_folder` and why `end_date` is needed? Perhaps if `start_date <- "28-02-2020"` and `results_folder <- "temp/"` then
`saveRDS(result, paste0(results_folder, "ouput_", end_date, ".RDS"))` may help.

Comment: If you run `end_date` in the console it returns is `-1996`. Should `end_date` be stored as string? `end_date <- "28-04-2020"`

Comment: Hi! x and y are any arbitrary values actually, the actual analysis I run is something else. results_folder is just a value defined for the data path where I am saving all results.

Your suggestion of (results_folder, "ouput_", end_date, ".RDS") worked great, thanks!